# Show small icon in Assets if image is being used in system or not?

Tags: assets, add-on-development

Looking for a way to show, with a little icon or other indicator, if a file in the [Assets](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/assets) module is used in the system or not, as this would be a great help to editors.

This would help while cleaning up large image collections, removing old files after a redesign, finding out which one of the duplicate images with similar names that is being used, and so on.

We have build this functionality into the front end version of a simpler media bank already, but the client would love the same functionality in the Assets module in the Control Panel as well. Interested in if somebody done something similar and/or can recommend a way of extending Assets this way (since we can't find any [hooks](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/assets/developers/hooks/index.html) for displaying files) before we jump in?